# can we use `:method => :post` parameter in `link_to` tag to hide parameter from URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

In the API for [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), you can see, you can pass an arguement, `:method => :post`. In Rails 2, it creates a form with POST verb and submits the form on clicking the link. But, can this be used to pass hidden fields to the form without appearing in URL? I mean building something like this:

```
<form name="test_form" action="/test/view" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="flag" name="flag" value=3 />
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="document.form.test_form.submit()">View</a>
```

that is something which does not make the `flag` parameter to appear in the url. I tried using `link_to` with `:method => :post`, but I am not sure how to pass the parameter `flag` to the `link_to`. When I tried this `link_to "View", {:controller => :test, :action => :view, :flag => 1}, :method => :post`, it is creating a form, but the url is still `/test/view?flag=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe all params passed to `link_to` will become a part of the URL. The solution is to either create a form by hand, or write your own helper to achieve exactly what you want.